# remembering auth details for excorporate with .netrc

Tags: authinfo

I've set up excorporate mode so that I can use emacs to read my outlook calendar.  However I am annoyed by having to input a username/password every time I open emacs.  I tried a `.netrc`:

```
machine outlook.office365.com login me@somewhere.com password 'secret'
```

But it doesn't work.  Can anyone point me further in the right direction?

Comment: I'd start by setting `auth-source-debug` to t, and looking in the `*Messages*` buffer. Perhaps you need a `port` keyword as well (I don't see excorporate calling auth-source, so it must be calling it indirectly if at all)

Comment: yep, that works outlook.office365.com:443 did it

Comment: Thank you for this useful question. Where did you put your .netrc file?

Comment: in my home directory

Comment: The file format and more details are explained in the [manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/auth/Help-for-users.html#Help-for-users)

Answer (score 2):

as per the comment from @rpluim adding the port `outlook.office365.com:443` did the job nicely:

```
machine outlook.office365.com:443 port https login john@email.com password changeme123
```

Don't forget that Emacs comes with built-in GPG support, so you can encrypt this file easily by naming it `~/.authinfo.gpg`

Comment: Just to add that this also work with .authinfo file.